# Notepad++ Regex How do I replace what is found with the same value but with a space in front?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Here is my regex:  `[0-9]+ thd`

It will find a number that has thd to the right of it.  Now how do I replace it with the same exact value but with a space in front of it?

I tried \1 \2 $1 $2 but that just causes it to get deleted.

If my regex finds the number 389 THD, I just want it to add a space in front of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you should use `" $0"` (without the quotes).

`$0` is the entire match, `$1` is the first capturing group, etc. Since there are no capturing groups in your regex, `$1` and `$2` are empty.

Comment: lol man what a simple solution, I just had no idea what to look for. Thanks

Comment: +1 Simple solution! (I myself got confused by the question, but yours is correct!)